# Unable to turn on Virtual Machine Windows Virtual Server 2005 R2

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, virtual-server-2005-r2

I have a standard virtual machine that is running windows 7 32-bit, on a a physical server running Windows Server 2008 64-bit. The virtual machine is running on Windows Virtual Server 2005.

When I go to try and turn the virtual machine on through the Windows Virtual Server admin panel I get the error message:

'The following error occurred:
The virtual machine could not be started. The virtual machine could not be started because the caller does not have execute access.'

I have access to the folders where the Virtual Machine files are stored, I can start, reset etc. other virtual machines on the same server with no issues.

The server that it is running on had to be restarted, after this I was not able to turn the VM back on. This VM has worked previously so it is confusing why I now can't change the configuration or turn the machine on.

I have also tried adding a new virtual machine using the existing files and still have the same issue.

Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have admin rights? did you add the VS2005 to the compatibility list (through gpedit)?

Comment: Yes I have admin rights, I'm not sure it would have anything to do with the compatibilty list. This machine has previously worked and after restarting the server it now will not allow me to turn it on.

Comment: Have you tried adding a new VM but copy only the VHD from the old VM?

Comment: Yeah I have tried that as well, still get the same error message. I can't change any of the configuration either. It seems like when it tries to change the .vnc file it can't access it or doesn't have write access. But I have checked this and I have all the right access and I can open the file and change it manually.

Comment: If I remember correctly there are two background services that relate to VS2005, maybe they need this permissions.
Can you test the problematic machine on Hyper-V or VirtualBox?
Also, if your on 2008 server, why not using Hyper-V (or VirtualBox) permanently?

Comment: Looks like the services are running, I've not tried running it in Hyper-V or virtual box, as this has worked previously and other Virtual machines that are pretty much a copy of that VM work correctly with no issues. I would like to migrate over to Hyper-V but this is on the company network and haven't been given the go ahead to do this yet.